# Accessing user profile picture from iCloud account

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

I'm attempting to pull a user's profile picture from their iCloud account. I'm using CloudKit and am verifying the user has an iCloud account as well as requesting discoverability permissions. I'm not sure this is possible but if it is I'd like to know how. Here is the relevant code:

To verify iCloud account:

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error) {
    if (accountStatus == CKAccountStatusAvailable)
    {
        self.shouldLogin = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.shouldLogin = NO;
    }
}];
```

To pull their profile image out of their iCloud account:

```
    [[CKContainer defaultContainer] requestApplicationPermission:CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability completionHandler:^(CKApplicationPermissionStatus applicationPermissionStatus, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (applicationPermissionStatus == CKApplicationPermissionStatusGranted)
    {
        [[CKContainer defaultContainer] discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID:self.dataStore.user.userID completionHandler:^(CKDiscoveredUserInfo * _Nullable userInfo, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSData *imageData = userInfo.displayContact.imageData;
            UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            self.profileImageView.image = profileImage;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I don't understand this question? This code works? yes or no? It reports and error, simply delivers nothing? Are you sure this data exists in CK? can you give a technical reference? Is this a public API or a private out-of-bounds one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get more than an unique ID plus the first and last name of an iCloud user. If you want more information, then you have to ask all users for that data.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, how would I go about doing that? Or did you mean I need to have the user go through some kind of process where they select a profile image?

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. There is no way to get other iCloud account information. If you want more like a profile picture, then you have to ask all users to upload a profile picture in your app.